# Next page link via the custom menu

Tags: menus, next-post-link

I would like to display a "next link" at the bottom of several page templates, using the actual custom menu in which they sit in. I built a function that mostly works except for an edge case (explained further). I wonder if you might see an obvious mistake of mine that could explain these?

Here is my function (inside functions.php)

```
/*
    FIND WHAT IS THE NEXT MENU ITEM FROM A GIVEN PAGE TEMPLATE
    used in The School pages to present teaser (bottom of the pages)

    usage: $next_post = get_next_menu_item('menu-id-name');
*/
function get_next_menu_item($menu_name){
    global $post;
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_name );
    $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    $i=-1;
    foreach ( $menuitems as $item ):
        $i++;
        $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
        if ($id == $post->ID){
            $next_id = $i;
        }
    endforeach;
    $next = $menuitems[$next_id+1];
    $next = get_post_meta( $next->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
    return get_post($next);

}
```

## Case where it returns a wrong menu object

I have a custom post type "staff". To be able to have a link to its content from the custom menus, I've created a page using the archive-staff.php template. 
On that page, my function retrieves an incorrect post.

The staff template recreates the main loop independently from the query_vars. Here it is, just in case it is important.

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bj_posts` p

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, meta_value as purpose
    FROM `bj_postmeta` pm 
    WHERE  `meta_key`='_staff_purpose'
    ) pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id
WHERE p.`post_type`='staff' AND p.`post_status`='publish'
ORDER BY purpose ASC, post_title ASC";

$staff_members = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Results through which I loop, and before calling my function, I reset the query.

```
 wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
$next_page = get_next_menu_item('the-school');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i solved the problem by renaming my Staff template from `archive-staff.php` to `page-staff.php` (or anything else for that matter), thus specifically telling Wordpress not to trust the template hierarchy logic and to consider that url as a "page" url, not a custom post type archive.

If you happen to have a use for this function, be aware that it will mainly work for page templates. Anything else needs to be tested, and post archives will not work.